# CSS - H1 Não se alinha no centro

Tags: html, css, html5

Olá! 
Fiz um código em que o meu logo é uma H1 e eu quero que ele fique alinhado sempre no centro da tela.
Por algum motivo ele não sai do lado esquerdo, não estou entendendo o motivo.
Podem me ajudar? Obrigado!

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(0, 76, 138);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cabecalho{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
}
nav{
    
    background-color: rgb(36, 40, 51);
}
ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  
}
ul li{
    margin-left:2.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-family:'Poppins' ;
}
ul li:hover{
    background-color: rgb(141, 141, 141);
}
.logo{
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 5em;
    padding-top: 0.4em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif';
}
.logo span{
    font-style: bold;
    color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
}
.titulo{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.habilidades{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 2em;
}
.habildiades_secao-01{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
.figure_html{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.figure_css{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.figure_javascript{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(255, 72, 0);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.figure_sql{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(116, 179, 0);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
.figure_aws{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
.figure_aws img{
    height: 8em;
}
.habilidades figure figcaption{
    margin-top: 1em;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    text-align: center;
}
.habilidades figure img{
    width: 7em;
    height: 8em;
}
.barra_de_habilidades{
    background-color: tomato;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 95%;
    height: 0.7em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_html,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_css,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_javascript,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_sql,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_aws{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1em;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0.2;
    height: 0.7em;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_html{
    width: 80%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_css{
    width: 90%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_javascript{
    width: 50%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_sql{
    width: 72%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_aws{
    width: 80%;
}
.p_de_dentro{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans|Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="habilidades.css">
    <title>BemRosselli</title>

</head>

<body>
    <header class="cabecalho">
        <h1 class="logo">BEM<span>Rosselli</span></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h2 class="titulo">Habilidades</h2>
        <section class="habilidades">
           
            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_html"> 
                    <img src="img/html.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de HTML">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de HTML</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_html"><p class="p_de_dentro">80%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_css">
                    <img src="img/css.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de CSS">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de CSS</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_css"><p class="p_de_dentro">90%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_javascript">
                    <img src="img/javascript.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de JavaScript">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de JavaScript</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_javascript"><p class="p_de_dentro">50%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_sql">
                    <img src="img/sql.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de SQL">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de SQL</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_sql"><p class="p_de_dentro">72%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_aws">
                    <img src="img/aws.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de AWS">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de AWS</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_aws"><p class="p_de_dentro">80%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, seu problema é que você está definindo uma largura fixa no seu `h1`. Com isso ele ficará alinhado à esquerda, o que é normal com todos os elementos.

O elemento `h1` é um elemento de bloco que ocupa por padrão toda a largura do seu contêiner e você está usando `text-align: center`, o que já é suficiente para alinhar o texto que tem dentro ao centro. Como dito, ao colocar `width: 5em` você está reduzindo a largura dele, e isso não é bom porque, além de alterar a natureza do elemento, o texto dentro dele não necessariamente terá a mesma largura. Veja que o texto ultrapassa a área do `h1` (o `h1` é o de verde):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra coisa é que ao usar `padding-left` irá descentralizar o texto, pois o `h1` irá ter um espaçamento à esquerda de `0.5em` fazendo com que o texto fique uns pixels a mais pra direita.

Apenas colocar `margin: auto` como propõe a outra resposta é maquiar o problema, pra não dizer que não resolve de fato, pois o texto não ficará centralizado, porque além do problema do `padding-left` citado, o texto está maior que o próprio `h1`, ou seja, o texto ficará bem mais à direita do que ao centro, como você pode ver neste print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que você tem que fazer é retirar o `width` e o `padding-left` e resetar as margens padrões do `h1`, aí sim o elemento irá ocupar toda a largura e o `texto-align: center` fará a sua função, que é alinhar o texto ao centro:

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(0, 76, 138);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cabecalho{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
}
nav{
    
    background-color: rgb(36, 40, 51);
}
ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  
}
ul li{
    margin-left:2.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-family:'Poppins' ;
}
ul li:hover{
    background-color: rgb(141, 141, 141);
}
.logo{
    /* padding-left: 0.5em; */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    /* width: 5em; */
    padding-top: 0.4em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif';
    margin: 0;
}
.logo span{
    font-style: bold;
    color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
}
.titulo{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.habilidades{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 2em;
}
.habildiades_secao-01{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
.figure_html{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.figure_css{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.figure_javascript{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(255, 72, 0);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.figure_sql{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(116, 179, 0);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
.figure_aws{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
.figure_aws img{
    height: 8em;
}
.habilidades figure figcaption{
    margin-top: 1em;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    text-align: center;
}
.habilidades figure img{
    width: 7em;
    height: 8em;
}
.barra_de_habilidades{
    background-color: tomato;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 95%;
    height: 0.7em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_html,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_css,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_javascript,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_sql,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_aws{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1em;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0.2;
    height: 0.7em;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_html{
    width: 80%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_css{
    width: 90%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_javascript{
    width: 50%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_sql{
    width: 72%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_aws{
    width: 80%;
}
.p_de_dentro{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans|Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="habilidades.css">
    <title>BemRosselli</title>

</head>

<body>
    <header class="cabecalho">
        <h1 class="logo">BEM<span>Rosselli</span></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h2 class="titulo">Habilidades</h2>
        <section class="habilidades">
           
            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_html"> 
                    <img src="img/html.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de HTML">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de HTML</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_html"><p class="p_de_dentro">80%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_css">
                    <img src="img/css.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de CSS">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de CSS</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_css"><p class="p_de_dentro">90%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_javascript">
                    <img src="img/javascript.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de JavaScript">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de JavaScript</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_javascript"><p class="p_de_dentro">50%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_sql">
                    <img src="img/sql.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de SQL">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de SQL</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_sql"><p class="p_de_dentro">72%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_aws">
                    <img src="img/aws.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de AWS">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de AWS</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_aws"><p class="p_de_dentro">80%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou muito bem!

Answer (score 0):

Bruno, como elementos `h1` têm, por padrão, display *block* você pode simplesmente 
fazer no CSS:

`h1{
   margin: auto; 
}`

Com essa configuração, todos os elementos `h1` ficam centralizados horizontalmente, já que, com essa configuração, são criadas margens laterais automáticas. O problema de aplicar isso diretamente à TAG é que todos os elementos `h1` ficarão centralizados. Para centralizar um em específico, use seu seletor.

Isto posto, seu código fica assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans|Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="habilidades.css">
    <title>BemRosselli</title>
    <style>
        body{
    background-color: rgb(0, 76, 138);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cabecalho{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
}
nav{
    
    background-color: rgb(36, 40, 51);
}
ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  
}
ul li{
    margin-left:2.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-family:'Poppins' ;
}
ul li:hover{
    background-color: rgb(141, 141, 141);
}
.logo{
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 5em;
    padding-top: 0.4em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif';
}
.logo span{
    font-style: bold;
    color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
}
.titulo{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
}


.habilidades{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 2em;
}
.habildiades_secao-01{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
.figure_html{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.figure_css{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.figure_javascript{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(255, 72, 0);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.figure_sql{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(116, 179, 0);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
.figure_aws{
    width: 7em;
    background-color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
.figure_aws img{
    height: 8em;
}
.habilidades figure figcaption{
    margin-top: 1em;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    text-align: center;
}
.habilidades figure img{
    width: 7em;
    height: 8em;
}
.barra_de_habilidades{
    background-color: tomato;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 95%;
    height: 0.7em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_html,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_css,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_javascript,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_sql,
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_aws{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1em;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0.2;
    height: 0.7em;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_html{
    width: 80%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_css{
    width: 90%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_javascript{
    width: 50%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_sql{
    width: 72%;
}
.barra_de_habilidades_dentro_aws{
    width: 80%;
}
.p_de_dentro{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1{
  margin: auto; <!-- Deixando o elemento h1 centralizado horizontalmente -->
}
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <header class="cabecalho">
        <h1 class="logo">BEM<span>Rosselli</span></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h2 class="titulo">Habilidades</h2>
        <section class="habilidades">
           
            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_html"> 
                    <img src="img/html.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de HTML">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de HTML</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_html"><p class="p_de_dentro">80%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_css">
                    <img src="img/css.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de CSS">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de CSS</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_css"><p class="p_de_dentro">90%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_javascript">
                    <img src="img/javascript.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de JavaScript">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de JavaScript</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_javascript"><p class="p_de_dentro">50%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_sql">
                    <img src="img/sql.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de SQL">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de SQL</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_sql"><p class="p_de_dentro">72%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="habilidades_secao-01">
                <figure class="figure_aws">
                    <img src="img/aws.png" alt="Icone da habilidade de AWS">
                    <figcaption>Habilidades de AWS</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="barra_de_habilidades">
                    <div class="barra_de_habilidades_dentro_aws"><p class="p_de_dentro">80%</p></div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!